# Tic Tac Toe: How to prove that there are 26,830 games possibilities

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I used the below code to get some statistics about the tic tac toe, I'm able to get the following numbers:

There are 138 terminal positions after assuming symmetries.

765 Positions

91 (X)

44 (O)

3 (tie)

But how to get the 26,830 games possibilities, from where I can extract and print this number?

The code I'm using created by [@Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown)

Original question: [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/tic-tac-toe-print-all-possible-positions-without-duplicates)

```
import re
from collections import Counter

FLIP_XFRM = [2,1,0,5,4,3,8,7,6]
ROT_XFRM = [6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2]

def xfrm(b, xf):
    return ''.join(b[xf[i]] for i in range(9))

def flipIt(b):
    return xfrm(b,FLIP_XFRM)

def rotIt(b):
    return xfrm(b,ROT_XFRM)

def conjugates(b):
    conj = [b, flipIt(b)]
    for i in range(3):
        conj += [rotIt(conj[-2]), rotIt(conj[-1])]
    return conj

def tttToB(n):
    b = ''
    for i in range(9):
        b = '.XO'[n %3]+b
        n /= 3
    return b

def printBoard(b,outcome='.'):
    print '%s\n%s\n%s %s\n' % (b[:3],b[3:6],b[6:],outcome)

def evalBoard(b):
    c = Counter(b)
    if c['X']-c['O'] not in [0,1]:
        return False

    p1 = 'XXX......|...XXX...|......XXX|X...X...X'
    p2 = p1.replace('X','O')

    br = rotIt(b)
    w1 = re.match(p1,b) or re.match(p1,br)    
    w2 = re.match(p2,b) or re.match(p2,br)    
    if w1 and w2:
        return False

    if w1:
        return 'X' if c['X']==c['O']+1 else False

    if w2:
        return 'O' if c['X']==c['O'] else False

    if '.' in b:
        return '.'
    else:
        return '/'

def main():
    history = set()
    for m in range(3**9):
        b = tttToB(m)
        if b not in history:
            outcome = evalBoard(b)
            if outcome:
                printBoard(b,outcome)
            history.update(conjugates(b))

main()
```

Comment: Well, there aren't 26,830 games possibilities. Who told you that?

Comment: "If players can make a move in any open space, and the game ends when either player makes three in a row, then there are 26,830 possible games" check the second table it says if there are 765 positions then there will be 26,830 terminal Paths.
 Source: [Mathematical Recreations](http://www.mathrec.org/old/2002jan/solutions.html)